# How to get runtime of one thread in kernel?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I need to get the process/thread time. I use `linux-4.13.4` in `Ubuntu 16.04`

I read some posts and get that

```
sum_exec_runtime

Total time process ran on CPU
In real time
Nano second units (10^−9)
Updated in __update_curr(), called from update_curr()
```

So I think if it is a single thread program. Somehow, I can get the running time of the thread by exact `sum_exec_runtime` from `task_struct`

I add syscall to get time:

So I make some little change inside linux kernel.

```
struct task_struct {
    ...
    ...
    struct sched_entity     se;    
    // TODO: to get start time and end time
    u64 start_time;  
    u64 end_time;
    ...
    ...
};
```

Then I add my syscall to store `sum_exec_runtime` into `start_time` and `end_time` when I call

`asmlinkage long sys_start_vm_timer(int __user vm_tid);`

`asmlinkage long sys_end_vm_timer(int __user vm_tid, unsigned long long __user *time);`

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(start_vm_timer,
                int __user, vm_tid){
        (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_start_time =
        (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->se.sum_exec_runtime;
        return 0;       
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(end_timer,
        int __user, tid,
        unsigned long long __user, *time){
    u64 vm_time;
    (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_end_time =
    (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->se.sum_exec_runtime;
    printk("-------------------\n");
    printk("end_vm_time: vm_elapsed_time = %llu \n", ((find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_end_time - (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_start_time) );
    vm_time = ((find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_end_time - (find_task_by_vpid(vm_tid))->vm_start_time);
    copy_to_user(time, &vm_time, sizeof(unsigned long long));
    return 0;
}
```

I test with this program tries to get the time of a for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    printf("tid = %d \n", tid);
    printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());
    printf("My parent's ID: %d\n", getppid());

    struct timeval start, end;
    unsigned long long elapsedTime = 0;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    syscall(336, tid);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 65535; i++){
        j += 1;
    }

    syscall(337, tid, &elapsedTime);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    printf("thread time = %llu microseconds \n", elapsedTime/1000);
    printf("gettimeofday = %ld microseconds \n", ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec)- (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)));
    return 0;
}
```

I get unexpected result.

```
wxf@wxf:/home/wxf/cPrj$ ./thread_time 
tid = 6905 
My process ID : 6905
My parent's ID: 6595
thread time = 0 microseconds 
gettimeofday = 422 microseconds
```

From `dmesg`,

```
[63287.065285] tid = 6905 
[63287.065288] start_vm_timer = 0 
[63287.065701] tid = 6905 
[63287.065702] -------------------
[63287.065703] end_vm_timer = 0 
[63287.065704] end_vm_time: vm_elapsed_time = 0
```

I expect that they should be almost the same. But why process/thread time is 0?

Comment: Are you sure that `for` loop didn't get optimized away. 1) It computes a result that is never used. 2) It's pretty easy to turn into `i=65535; j=65535;`

Comment: @MFisherKDX I test it even using `gcc -o0 thread_time thread_time.c` and add printf to print `j` to use it, still `sum_exec_runtime` is 0

Answer (score 1):

The value of `sum_exec_runtime` does not include the current runtime of the thread. It's updated when needed, not continuously. See the `update_curr` function.

Comment: I think it is accumulated and includes the current runtime of the thread as `curr->sum_exec_runtime += delta_exec;`.

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h#L209